# Using BASH to copy folder if contents are under 4gb total

Tags: macos, bash, terminal

I have this script copying directories

```
for dir in $(pwd)/*/
do
        dir=${dir%*/}
        dirsize=$(du -chk "${dir##*/}" | grep total)
        kbsize=${dirsize%total}
        if [[ "$kbsize" -lt 4194304 ]]
        then
                cp -rv * "$1"
        fi
done
```

I'm trying to get it to only copy directories if they are under 4GB (because of FAT32 limitation). The problem is it copies everything, not just directories over 4GB.

I'm sure it's something dumb as my BASH knowledge isn't that great. Any ideas?

Comment: Use the `-s` option of `du`, it is simpler to parse

Comment: Use `if (( $kbsize < 4194304 )); then...` as a more-readable alterntative for numerical comparisions.

Comment: @chepner I've tried that, but it gives me a bunch of syntax errors for some reason.

Comment: @adamzwakk: are you sure you're using `bash`, then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `*` in your cp statement is being expanded to include all directory names in `pwd`.  therefore, if any directory is under 4gb, it will try to copy every directory.

i'd suggest you use the `-t` option to `cp` to specify a target directory to which the files should be copied and remove the * from that command.

also, as others have mentioned, check out the `-s` option to `du`.

Comment: Right! I never thought of the * copying the whole thing, I'll try this and see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your `du` command. Running this command yields:

```
$ du -chk .
# ...
18M     total
```

As a result, your `kbsize` variable contains `18M`. And `bash` doesn't like that:

```
$  [[ 18M -lt 923898 ]]; echo $?
bash: [[: 18M: value too great for base (error token is "18M")
1
```

Replace your command with `du -sk`:

```
$ kbsize=$(du -sk . | awk '{print $1}')
$ echo $kbsize
18196
$ [[ $kbsize -lt 4194304 ]]; echo $?
0 # Success!
$ [[ $kbsize -lt 10 ]]; echo $?
1 # Fails, but no errors
```